Virtual Device successfully downloaded but not showing on android studio avd manager
I'm having a problem with my android studio, i tried to create an android virtual device, in hardware section i selected pixel 6a Playstore. And in system images i selected release name "S" API 31, ABI x86_64, android 12.
when the download has finished with no errors, I restarted android studio, expecting that i should see the avd, but there's nothing.
here in my directory where the system image is saved

and here in the system image download, it shows that i haven't install or download "S" but i already downloaded it

I'm using Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
I switched to create the AVD manually using avdmanager like the docs said, but it's not working and confusing me
C:\Users\SMC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk>avdmanager create avd --force --name MyAVD --package "system-images;android-31;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...
Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
null

need some help please

Have you tried booting up the AVD?

i have no avd listed to boot it, it's not even listing the avd i have downloaded
